# Jenkins losing configuration

Tags: jenkins

I downloaded the jenkins war and su into the jenkins user and ran the following command

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

I setup the configuration and when I rebooted the computer and loaded it up, all the configuration was gone. I checked the /home/jenkins/.jenkins and all the directories appear to be there. Looking at the system info section in jenkins I see the home directory set right

```
HOME   /home/jenkins
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out. I just had to as the jenkins user export the JENKINS_HOME variable and that did it